# Update version in setup.py before uploading package to pypicloud

Tags: python, file, pypi

I am automating the deployment of my python packages to pypicloud. For this I need to update the `setup.py` file and increase the version by 1 before creating and uploading the package. Looking for a solution using simple file handling in python. Any other leads will also help.

Contents of `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='XXX',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests')),
    description='ABC',
    # change to version='0.2.3'
    version='0.2.2',
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=["numpy==1.16.0", "pandas==0.23.3", "exrex==0.10.5",
                      "pymongo==3.5.1", "requests==2.18.4", "elasticsearch==6.1.1",
                      "jellyfish==0.6.1", "roman==3.1", "python_Levenshtein==0.12.0",
                      "findspark==1.3.0", "pyspark==2.4.4", "py4j==0.10.7"]
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`bump`](https://pypi.org/project/bump/) package for this:

```
$ bump
1.0.1

$ git diff setup.py
─────────────────────────────────────────────────
modified: setup.py
─────────────────────────────────────────────────
@ setup.py:6 @ from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='bump',
-    version='1.0.0',
+    version='1.0.1',
    description='Bumps package version numbers',
    long_description=open('README.rst').read(),
    license='MIT',
```